# What does "ValueError: object too deep for desired array" mean and how to fix it?

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, valueerror

I'm trying to do this:

```
h = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]

Y = np.convolve(Y, h, "same")
```

`Y` looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

While doing this I get this error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Why is this?

My guess is because somehow the `convolve` function does not see `Y` as a 1D array.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `Y` array in your screenshot is not a 1D array, it's a 2D array with 300 rows and 1 column, as indicated by its `shape` being `(300, 1)`.

To remove the extra dimension, you can slice the array as `Y[:, 0]`. To generally convert an n-dimensional array to 1D, you can use `np.reshape(a, a.size)`.

Another option for converting a 2D array into 1D is `flatten()` function from `numpy.ndarray` module, with the difference that it makes a copy of the array.

Comment: To convert that array to 1D array, you can also use squeeze()

Comment: Even simpler (and more accurate), instead of len(a) use: a.size

Comment: @Ari Why more accurate? `size` is documented to return the number of elements in the array, which seems to me like the exact same thing as `len()` returns.

Comment: len(a) gives the "length" along one axis only. For multi-dimensional arrays (2D and above) it is better to use 'size'.

Comment: @Ari Oh, now I see what you mean: `size` is the product of lengths across dimensions. Using `a.size` makes the recipe correctly reshape arrays with more than two dimensions, where using `len` would fail with "total size of new array must be unchanged". Thanks for the hint, I've now updated the answer.

Comment: `.squeeze()` is probably the most correct choice in this situation.

Answer (score 12):

`np.convolve()` takes one dimension array. You need to check the input and convert it into 1D.

You can use the `np.ravel()`, to convert the array to one dimension.

Answer (score 4):

`np.convolve` needs a flattened array as one of its inputs, you can use `numpy.ndarray.flatten()` which is quite fast, find it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `scipy.ndimage.convolve` it allows convolution of multidimensional images. [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) is the docs