# How to find index of the window which has certain number of values greater than threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have just started learning python and struggling with this code. I have a dataframe which looks like shown in graph.

I want to find the first occurrence of the window in the dataframe which has certain number of values greater than threshold.

For Exmaple:

Let's say dataframe is 1000000 values in dimension. I want divide this in sliding window of 1000 and need to know whether this 1000 values alteast have 10 values which are greater than certain threshold. If first window (point 0-999) does not have the atleast 10 values greater than certain threshold, window will slide and consider values 1-1000. I have to find the index of the first occurrence of window which has atleast 10 values greater than threshold.

Also as I am dealing here streaming data, I need to stop the search when such window in dataframe occurs.

I tried this code but getting key error and not able to solve the problem.

```
for i in np.arange(0,len(data)-999):
    for j in np.arange(0,1000):
        if data[i+j]>threshold:
            var_count=var_count+1
        if var_count>10:
            print("Anomaly has occurred")
```

Sample data looks like this which has around 1.8 million rows.

[image]

Sample data could looke like this

```
data_sample=[1,1,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,1]            
data_sample=pd.DataFrame(data_sample)

threshold=1
window=5
```

in that I need at least 2 values which are greater than `1` which would return the index 18 as at that index my window of length 5 has at least 2 values which are greater than 1.

Comment: How do you get to 11? By index 8 you have 2 values above 1. You only get 3 values ab0ve 1 at index 12...

Comment: I had updated the wrong sample data, I have again updated the question with correct data.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with convolution:

```
threshold = 10
window_size = 5
count_threshold = 3

kernel = np.ones(window_size)
over_threshold = (data['relevant_column'] > threshold).values
running_count = np.convolve(kernel, over_threshold)
np.nonzero(running_count >= count_threshold)[0]
```

Or a similar idea using pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum):

```
np.where(((data['relevant_column'] > threshold).rolling(window_size).sum() >= count_threshold))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one followup question.                    
over_threshold = (data['relevant_column'] > threshold).values                           
Would it not require to consider entire dataframe for this line of code? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: It depends on your DataFrame. You didn't give any example data so it's impossible to know. It sounded like you were only looking in a single column. Perhaps add some simple sample data with your expected output. Keep it small, ~10 values.

Comment: I have added the sample data. My sample data is just one column dataframe which has around 1.8 million rows. For that I am getting this error> ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: @Bhakti please make your sample data code, not an image. Code like `pd.DataFrame([...], columns=[...])` and also include the **expected output**. You don't have to use real values, use ones that demonstrate the principle. Use a small rolling window of like 4 instead of 1000 etc.

Comment: As for your error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923081/valueerror-object-too-deep-for-desired-array-while-using-convolution

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question including sample data.

Comment: Your problem is that you aren't giving the column a name so I assume you're not extracting the series. You need to do it. If you refuse to give it a name then change `data['relevant_column']` to `data[0]`.

Comment: I am not getting an error when I sliced the dataframe, but I also got result which was simply greater than threshold.

Comment: @Bhakti subtract the `window_size` from the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.